# getting error in a console vue - cannot read null of a $ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops, date, templates

I wonder why I'm getting an error in a console vue - cannot read null of a $ref. While the html template is correct and I'm adding logic to the script tag as required. But still getting this error - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style'). I'm defining the template $refs as it is written in vue docs, but it seems like vue doesn't accepts it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wave-de7yk5?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-2494

```js
<template>
  <div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand secHand" ref="secHand"></div>
      <div class="hand minHand" ref="minHand"></div>
      <div class="hand hourHand" ref="hourHand"></div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <select
      name="box-1"
      id="select"
      @Change="selectedHour"
      v-model="selectedHour"
    >
      <option class="option" value="0">0 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="1">+1 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="2">+2 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="3">+3 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="4">+4 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="5">+5 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="6">+6 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="7">+7 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="8">+8 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="9">+9 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="10">+10 UTC</option>
      <option class="option" value="11">+11 UTC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".secHand");
const minuteHand = document.querySelector(".minHand");
const hourHand = document.querySelector(".hourHand");

// const select = document.querySelector("#select");
// let selectValue = select.value;

let secHand = this.$refs.secHand;
function setDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  const seconds = now.getSeconds();
  const secondsDegrees = (seconds / 60) * 360 + 90;
  this.secHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondsDegrees}deg)`; // getting the error at this line
  if (secondsDegrees === 90) {
    secHand.style.transition = "none";
  } else if (secondsDegrees >= 91) {
    secHand.style.transition = "all 0.05s cubic-bezier(0.1, 2.7, 0.58, 1)";
  }

  const minutes = now.getMinutes();
  const minutesDegrees = (minutes / 60) * 360 + 90;
  minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minutesDegrees}deg)`;

  const hours = now.getHours();

  let newHour = hours + selectValue;

  const hoursDegrees = (newHour / 12) * 360 + 90;
  hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hoursDegrees}deg)`;
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      selectedHour: "",
    };
  },
  props: {},
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `this.$refs` in your code outside Vue.js.

```
let secHand = this.$refs.secHand;
```

If you want to access `$refs`, you should do it inside Vue.js App, not outside!

Put your `setDate()` function as method inside Vue and it will work.

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedHour: "",
    };
  },
methods: {
   setDate() {
     let secHand = this.$refs.secHand;
   }
}
```

For dynamic css styles you can also use the Vue [SFC CSS Features](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html)

See [Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html)

Comment: I've edit the code actually, but it still doesn't work